# Many MVP's for the same page?

Tags: gwt, mvp, gwt-mvp

I have started experimenting with GWT 2.8 and MVP pattern.

I want to make a simple browser app that sends and fetches data from client to server, **that has only one page**.

Should I use only one MVP that handles everything in the page?

Or can I use many  MVP's that implement different parts of the page?

For example, one MVP would handle the adding updating entities part of the page. The other would handle the presentation of the entities. Another one something else.

Is it a good practise to use many MVPs for the same page?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a mvp pattern even in small cases. It will make it much easier to expand a one pager later and to maintain everything.

But, I would not use Activities & Places, [Domino-MVP](https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-mvp) and [Nalu](https://github.com/NaluKit/nalu) offer much better implementation, easier to understand and much more light-weighted.

Both offer artifact creators which make the start very easy.

Use the Gitter room to ask questions. ([Domino room](https://gitter.im/DominoKit/domino), [Nalu room](https://gitter.im/Nalukit42/Lobby))